# PHP array_count_values with multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 123 [name] => Alex ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 124 [name] => John ) 
    [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 123 [name] => Alex ) 
    [3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 124 [name] => John) 
    [4] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 126 [name] => Paul )
 )
```

And I want to output like the following:

```
 Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 123 [name] => Alex [count] = 2 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 124 [name] => John [count] = 2 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 126 [name] => Paul [count] = 1 )
  )
```

I tried using `array_count_values($array)`, but it doesn't work.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `array_map` along with simple `foreach` like as

```
foreach(array_map("get_object_vars",$arr) as $val){
    $hash = $val['id'];
    if(isset($result[$hash])){
        $result[$hash]['count'] += $result[$hash]['count'];
    }else{
        $result[$hash] = $val;
        $result[$hash]['count'] = 1;
    }
}
print_r(array_values($result));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [name] => Alex
            [count] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 124
            [name] => John
            [count] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 126
            [name] => Paul
            [count] => 1
        )

)
```